# 2002 Stratus doesn't crank when key turned (radio is also off)

Tags: dodge, starter, stratus

When I turn the key, there is no response at all, the engine doesn't make any sounds like it's trying to crank, no clicks, or any other visual or audio response of any kind.

The lights still work, as does the digital odometer, and the blower for the AC, and the power windows/locks, but the radio is off as well.

What I've tried:
A friend recommended jumping it off; tried it. No luck
I tried replacing the #8 fuse based on what I'd read online (that should be the starter fuse, yes?).  No luck on that either.
Then I checked the rest of the fuses one by one, and none of them looked blown.

Any suggestions as to what this could be or how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the battery is supplying electricity to the car, but it's not getting to the starter motor.

When you turn the key and there's not even a click, my first thought is a bad starter relay, but it could also be a loose wire, or a bad ignition switch. It should be pretty easy to check, have someone turn the key while you touch the relay. If there's nothing, not even a vibration, then the problem is the relay, the ignition switch, or somewhere in between.

I'm not familiar with the 2002 Stratus, but from my searches it looks like the starter relay is in the PDC, near the battery. [Here's a diagram showing the PDC of a Stratus.](http://ww2.justanswer.com/uploads/tsmodie/2010-05-11_200007_fuse.jpg) It's from a discussion about turn signals, but it shows the location of the starter relay.

From my searches, I also see lots of other Stratus starter relay problems, so this may be a common problem.